# Notification manager doesnt show any sort of notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm very new to android and I have an GCM client and server which is working fine. When the app is running I get the notification from the server.

But when the app is not running I didn't get any response.

Here is the code that I use for generating notifications:

```
   private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = 1;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

which is called through:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        generateNotification(context, "Tock Tock");
    }
```

when I see the logcat I get an error like this:

```
 Unable to find resource: 1
W/ImageView(   58): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:489)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:592)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:989)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:286)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/ImageView(   58):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/ImageView(   58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:506)
```

Not sure where I'm making the mistake. I'm following the sample tutorial from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `int icon = 1;`.

You should add a real resource id there, so it will be shown in the notification bar. You get the `Resources$NotFoundException` because no resource found with id `1`.

For example, if you put an image called `xyz.png` into the `res/drawable` folder, the image's id will be `R.drawable.xyz` which can be called from code like:

```
int icon = R.drawable.xyz;
```